# Can't uninstall any apps from Ubuntu Software

Tags: 16.04, software-center, uninstall, error-handling

[image]

So, to clean up some space on my Ubuntu partition on a dual boot laptop, I wanted to remove some apps that I wasn't using and didn't plan to use in the future. Each time I click on the "Remove" button, I get the error "Sorry, this didn't work. Removal of [app name] failed" as in the picture (and, after that, the app that failed to be removed appears twice in the list of installed apps on Ubuntu Software). This happens on ALL apps. I had some trouble when using the After Installer, a couple of the last apps it installed didn't install properly and I think that that's what might be causing the issue, but I have no clue how to fix it. Help?

Edit: tried to delete it from terminal, here's the screenshot of the result

[image]

Comment: Can you try uninstalling it from the command-line? Please open a terminal, type `sudo apt remove shotwell` (you'll be asked for your admin password) and then copy the output (select with mouse and right-click/Copy, not Ctrl+C) and [edit] your question to paste it here.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use code formatting.

Comment: first timer here, I didn't know how to use code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attempted to install Oracle Java 7 at some point, which seemingly has failed and left the package `oracle-java7-installer` in a broken, half-installed state.

This package is actually just a downloader/installer, which tries to download the real software from Oracle's website during the installation. This failed though, because the files to download seem to have been (re)moved by Oracle and now it fails with a 404 "Not found" error.

To remove this package, running the command below should be sufficient:

```
sudo apt purge oracle-java7-installer
```

After that, I suggest to also run these other commands below to make sure your package system is in best shape. It will update your list of available packages (happens automatically every day anyway), check if any of your installed packages can be upgraded (and do so), and remove some no longer needed packages, which were listed in the output you showed in your question, like a few Python libraries and an old kernel:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: yes, Java Oracle is one of the packages that the After Installer gave me problems with …

Comment: After doing this, I rebooted and it seems to have worked… thanks!

Comment: @GuidoCatSilva If this solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the round check button on its left.